# Be $E,F,K , L,$ points in the sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$ of a square $ABCD$, respectively. Show that if $EK$ $\perp$ $FL$ , then $EK=FL$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

Be $E,F,K , L,$ points in the sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$ of a square $ABCD$, respectively. Show that if  $EK$ $\perp$ $FL$ , then $EK=FL$.

I need help proving something like this:

[image]

Any hints?

Edited: I wrote the principal statement wrong, now it's correct.

I saw a question in this forum about a similar problem, the problem was like this:
[image]

And i thought that i can modify the problem like the first image, and after drawing a lot of squares in geogebra, i think it's true, but i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The property doesn't hold. Consider: Let one segment be a diagonal, and let the other join, say, the midpoints of adjacent sides. The segments will be perpendicular, but the midpoint-segment will be only half as long as the diagonal.

Comment: So the property holds in all the cases but the cases where one segment is the diagonal and the other isn't?

Comment: You can nudge the diagonal segment ever-so-slightly into not being a diagonal anymore, and likewise nudge the midpoint segment so that it stays perpendicular. The second segment will still be far shorter than the first.

Comment: @RodrigoPizarro No. In both of your illustrations, you can slide one of the segments along the other while maintaining perpendicularity. As an extreme case, move the vertical-ish segment in the second diagram as far to the right as possible. The resulting segment is obviously much shorter than the stationary one. I suspect that radiating from a pair of vertices is a necessary condition.

Comment: I'm going to rework the question properly to a condition that i think it's true always. Thanks.

Comment: You should make clear that you are trying to formulate a true statement, so that people don't waste time trying to prove a falsehood. (Comments are easily overlooked, so add this context in the question itself.) You should also explain the purpose of the question; for instance, did an instructor challenge you to invent a new theorem? were you just sketching lines and squares when you noticed what you thought was a pattern? are you perhaps mis-remembering a challenge you read online? Such information can help people understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Blue I think the statement is correct, while your example does not reflect that $E,F,K,L$ lie on $AB, BC,CD, DA$ in that order.

Comment: @QuangHoang i edited the question. Blue is correct. The example that Blue gave was for the previous problem.

Comment: @QuangHoang: The statement might very well be correct, now. However, OP first posted a false statement (which my counter-example refuted), and later modified it into "a condition that **i think** it's true always" (quoting comment above, **emphasis** mine). It's important for the reader to know that this is an attempted (and possibly-flawed) reconstruction of a forum challenge, not a verbatim textbook exercise or somesuch.

Comment: @Blue totally agreed on the **I think** part. I was commenting on your counter-example without realizing that it was on the question's first revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, your problem is equivalent to the later problem. See the picture below, where $AG\parallel FL$ and $BH\parallel EK$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $ABCD$ be our square, $L\in AD$, $F\in BC$, $K\in DC$ and $E\in AB$ such that $LF\perp KE.$

Now, let $R$ be a rotation by $90^{\circ}$ of the plane around the center of the square.

Let $R(L)=L'$ and $R(F)=F'.$

Thus, $L'F'||KE$ and since $KF'||EL',$ we obtain $$KE=F'L'=FL.$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In a unit square draw two perp lines with an arbitrary slope $\alpha$  from its corners.

Both these inside lines $(DE,LF)$  have equal length $L=\sec \alpha$

Length $L$ remains constant only by arbitrary parallel translation of line segments $DE,LF$ along $(x,y)$ arrow directions shown within the square and restricted to vertical/horizontal sides of square.